# Return a value from angular $http.get in datatables.js column's render function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables, promise, angular-promise

I have a datatables.js table set up in an angular 1.2 project. I want a value from an $http.get(...) call to be what is displayed in one of the cells of each row of the table.

I know that $http returns a promise, but I can't figure out how to change the code so that the value of the resolved promise is what is returned by the render function so that the data & not the promise is what is displayed in the table.

---

**UPDATED: Do I need to pre-fetch the data before the table is created? <-- This is the answer!** See the selected answer for implementation. You can't make the call for every row within the table using something like Angulars $http because there is no opportunity to return the resolved promises data within the render function.

---

I'm not looking for a hack unless it is necessary. I would like to solve this with a known pattern.

Here is a fiddle of what I'm trying to do: [jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/trgsxqnx/8/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="salutationApp">
        <div ng-controller="salutationReportController">
            <table id="salutationTable" />
            <button type="button" ng-click="init()">
                Create Table
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/t/dt/jq-2.2.0,dt-1.10.11/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.29/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

var salutationApp = angular.module("salutationApp", []);
salutationApp.controller("salutationReportController", ["$http", "$scope", function ($http, $scope) {
    var getSalutationLink = function (data) {
        var url = 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1';
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: url,
            params: data
        });
    };

    var init = function () {
        var salutationDataSource = [
          {
              salutationDataField: "hello!"
          },
          {
              salutationDataField: "good morning!"
          },
          {
              salutationDataField: "greeetings!"
          }
        ];

        $("#salutationTable").DataTable({
            "bDestroy": true,
            data: salutationDataSource,
            columns: [{
                title: "Salutation",
                data: "salutationDataField",
                render: function (cellData, type, fullRowData, meta) {
                    //I want this to return a some data from the server
                    var retVal = getSalutationLink({
                        salutation: cellData,
                    });

                    return retVal; // I know this is a promise... but I need to return the value of the resolved promise. I want the data from the web server to be the return value. This is where I'm stuck.
                }
            }]
        });

    };

    $scope.init = function () {
        init();
    };
}]);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your `ng-controller` would even work? You don't set it to a global variable name, it has to be declared within angular.

**html**

```
<div ng-controller="SalutationReportController">
    <div id="salutationTable"></div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
//this shouldn't work
var SalutationReportController = function() { /* blah */ }

//this would work
angular
    .module('app')
    .controller('SalutationReportController', ['$http', '$scope', function() {
        $http.get('/api/foobar').then(function(res) {
            //now the data you got from the promise is publicly available to your child directive
            $scope.tabledata = res.data;
        });
    }])
```

Somewhere in the code for your directive you'll need to add the correct scope properties and have the directive inherit the property according to its api.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I was just pulling pieces out of our project & renaming them while trying to figure out how to set up an angular app in jsfiddle and didn't do a very good job. I'll update the fiddle. Thanks for your contribution!

Comment: I think the moral of the story is that I need to get all of the data & associate it correctly before hand. Seeing your example lets me see that, now. I'll attempt this and get back with the results.

Comment: This is the basic example you'll see all over the place but it's the worst way to do it. Once you get it working switch to `$resource` or a library like js-data or restacular. The example I provided will only lead to spaghetti code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in to Angular-datatables?

http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withPromise

```
angular.module('showcase.withPromise', ['datatables', 'ngResource']).controller('WithPromiseCtrl', WithPromiseCtrl);

   function WithPromiseCtrl(DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $resource) {
   var vm = this;
       vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromFnPromise(function() {
          return $resource('data.json').query().$promise;
   }).withPaginationType('full_numbers');

    vm.dtColumns = [
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
       DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
  ];
}
```

Comment: I have seen it available, but this is the last requirement on this project & it might be difficult to meet deadlines if we switch over. From your experience, is it an easy switch? Tables we are using have a lot of customization already.

Comment: Basic functions should work in similar manner as with regular Datatables. They are just implimented in different ways. I recommend looking in to documentation and binding data with ng-repeat is always useful.

Comment: Thanks for the info! I started Datatables because I got a lot out of the box in a few lines of code. After that, any customization started to feel like I was doing an SAP implementation :)